# A string literal was expected in SQL Server XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to execute this code as you can see

```
UPDATE InquiryStatus
SET TotalCarburetorResult.modify(N'insert <item model=sql:variable("@Model") CarType=sql:variable("@CarType") SystemType=sql:variable("@SystemType")><count>1</count></item> into (/Result)[1]') where  UserId=@userid and SubmitDatetime=convert(date,@SubmitDatetime)
```

But I get this error :

> Msg 2225, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
>   XQuery [InquiryStatus.TotalCarburetorResult.modify()]: A string literal was expected

As a note when I execute this query with this format it worked:

```
UPDATE InquiryStatus
SET TotalCarburetorResult.modify(N'insert <item CarType="پراید" SystemType="2" model="1382"><count>100</count></item> into (/Result)[1]')
```

Comment: I found the problem it because of " .when i use sql:variable how can i add " inside my variable like this : model="sql:variable("@Model")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution

```
    declare @myxml xml
    set @myxml='<item model="'+@Model+'" CarType="'+@CarType+'" SystemType="'+@SystemType+'"><count>1</count></item>'


UPDATE InquiryStatus
SET TotalCarburetorResult.modify(N'insert sql:variable("@myxml") into (/Result)[1]') where  UserId=@userid and SubmitDatetime=convert(date,@SubmitDatetime)
```